# Setting Up Development Tree

Tags: continuous-integration, development-environment, project-setup

Any advice on best practices for setting up development tree for .net application using with continuous integration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Read the [blog series from Mike Roberts](http://mikebroberts.com/blog/Tech/dotNet/) on the subject.
- There is a tool that might be suitable for your needs: [TreeSurgeon](http://treesurgeon.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this will be a dupe, but I can't see it on the 'related' list, so I'll at least reply with my environment:

1. buildserver
2. SVN
3. TortiseSVN
4. trac
5. CC.net
6. NAnt (to do builds on the buildserver)
7. automatic deployment system [using custom in-house one at the moment]
8. NUnit
9. log4net

Various other things as-per the specific project.